# <Kivy> Why is my python code not showing the buttons?

Tags: python, button, widget, kivy

The point of the following code is to show a list of Buttons(like a menu) that you'd use to change the screens, now ... It doesn't work at all and I can't see where the problem is

I used to get "typeerror **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" and I made it dissapear by creating a new class for the screen then I got app.root instance is not set and now I'm not getting any errors

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import random
import main
kivy.require('1.10.1')

 class Game(BoxLayout):
    layout = BoxLayout(padding=5, orientation="vertical")
    colors = [(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)]
    Buttonz= ('Button1', 'Button2', 'Button3', 'Button4')
    def Buttons(self):
        for i in range(len(self.Buttonz)):
            btn = Button(text=self.Buttonz[i],background_color=random.choice(self.colors))
            self.layout.add_widget(btn)
            btn.bind(on_press=main.Political)
        return self.layout


class Main(App):

    title='ButtonGame'
    def build(self):
       return Game()

if __name__ == '__main__':

   Main().run()
```

I expected the code to show 4 buttons with randomly picked colors from the 4 I declared, but it shows an entirely black screen instead. The buttons are supposed to change to another screen from a different module. Perhaps I should use ScreenManager in both of the modules??? ( Sorry for the horrible indentation I tried to format the code as it should be on here, but I couldn't )

Comment: The indentation still isn't right.  Please fix.  `class Game(BoxLayout)` should have stuff indented underneath it, and it doesn't.

Comment: I fixed it just now, I hope I didn't miss anything in the post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a constructor to invoke `Buttons` method.

## Snippets

```
class Game(BoxLayout):
    layout = BoxLayout(padding=5, orientation="vertical")
    colors = [(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)]
    Buttonz = ('Button1', 'Button2', 'Button3', 'Button4')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Buttons()
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

    def Buttons(self):
        for i in range(len(self.Buttonz)):
            btn = Button(text=self.Buttonz[i], background_color=random.choice(self.colors))
            self.layout.add_widget(btn)
            btn.bind(on_press=main.Political)
```

## Example

The following example only use one `BoxLayout` widget as the root.

### main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import random
# import main


class Game(BoxLayout):
    colors = [(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)]
    Buttonz = ('Button1', 'Button2', 'Button3', 'Button4')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.padding = 5
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.Buttons()

    def Buttons(self):
        for i in range(len(self.Buttonz)):
            btn = Button(text=self.Buttonz[i], background_color=random.choice(self.colors))
            self.add_widget(btn)
            # btn.bind(on_press=main.Political)


class Main(App):
    title = 'ButtonGame'

    def build(self):
        return Game()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]